# Error with Evaluate Function

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following legacy code which is causing a stange issues just recently, we upgraded to coldfusion 9

```
<cfquery name="qCheck" datasource="#ds#">
    select * from authentication
    where id = #val(url.ID)#>
</cfquery>
```

so the above query does return a row and it has stored value in one of its field which is following as:

*columnName - vchevalemailaddress
Value as - session.email*

```
<cfset a = Evaluate(qCheck.vchevalemailaddress)
<cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>
```

Now i am getting an error as:

**Element EMAIL is undefined in SESSION.**

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the evaluate function.  It's an undefined variable.  cfdump your session scope to see what is in there.

Comment: You could also do `<cfif isDefined(qCheck.vchevalemailaddress)>` before attempting to use evaluate() on it

Comment: yes, @dan, I am also thinking on same thing but i am still checking where the problem lies, will update on the same

Comment: You do not need to use `evaluate()` in the query you posted, and you should be using `cfqueryparam`, though.

Comment: ok, so you are saying , i should remove the evalaute function, let me try that

Comment: I ran this as a different page, not inside the project, i still get an error, why so

Comment: He's not using evaluate in the query.  He's using it on the returned value, which is "session.email".  He is using val() in the query.  That is what's unnecessary.

Comment: My bad....I meant to say you do not need the `val()` in the query and you should be using `cfqueryparam`. Why is the value of the column vchevalemailaddress 'session.email'? This seems like a less than optimal way of handling this.

Comment: This is quite old application and still i am trying to understand why they are storing session.email in database.